# How to use @PostContruct in Spring Boot app to insert data into db juct once, when we are starting the app for the first time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot app, and I am using service class where I have values for initial loading.
I have method annotated with **@PostContruct** annotation.
My question is, is it possible to use this annotation only for the first time when we are starting our app, just to insert data once? And every time when we start up our app after that to ignore initial load?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You should use something like Flyway /https://flywaydb.org/) or Liquibase (https://liquibase.org/) for that.

Comment: Flyway and liquibase is best option for you

Answer (score 0):

While the comment is definitely correct, I can imagine you are just starting out and don't want the additional complexity of configuring db migration tool.

Just incorporate a basic check logic into your Bootstrap class, like so:

```
@Component
public class DataGenerator {
   @Autowired
   private YourRepository yourRepository;

   @PostConstruct
   public void generate() {
       if(yourRepository.findById("id").isEmpty()) { //assuming you are retuning Optional 
          //do bootstrapping data
       }
   }
}
```